# Buscar valor Array de Objetos

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
jsonOptions = [{"description": "Carro 1", "product": "4"},
                {"description": "Carro 2", "product": "5"},
                {"description": "Carro 3", "product": "6"},
                {"description": "Carro 4", "product": "7"},
                {"description": "Carro 5", "product": "8"}

              ];
```

Utilizo ele para preencher um `<select>` utilizando o valor de `description` para construir o `<option>`

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = item.description;
    dataList.appendChild(option);
});
```

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é: Quando eu seleciono uma das opções, ele envia o valor que foi capturado, então no caso, se eu seleciono o primeiro valor ele me retorna o texto "Carro 1".. Show!

O que eu precisava era tipo, se o valor selecionado foi Carro 1, ele pegar o segundo valor e lançar numa variável. Seria tipo:

Envia carro 1 para uma variável
Depois buscar o segundo valor "4" e jogar para outra variável

Comment: Não saiu as tags que escrevi.. "Preencher um <select>" e "construir o <option>"

Comment: Quando precisar, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268576/edit) a pergunta Alexandre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atribua o `value` de `option`:

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = item.description;
    option.value = item.product;
    dataList.appendChild(option);
});
```

Comment: E depois busco o valor assim:

var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

Caraca, eu não sei se fico feliz ou com raiva.. Muito obrigado cara.